# PHP Fann gives same result despite different inputs

Tags: php, machine-learning, neural-network, fann

I am trying out the FANN PHP module and I was able to successfully run the example here http://php.net/manual/en/fann.examples-1.php

I modified it to be able to handle 5 inputs with an arbitrary function for output. I generated 1000 training data and run the training for the neural network. However, upon testing the output has duplicate results for different inputs.

This is a fragment of the training data. The function is `$x = round($a + $b * $c / $d - $e, 2)`. so `35 + 33 * 31 / 25 - 48 = 27.92`

```
1000 5 1
35 33 31 25 48
27.92
74 3 1 26 94
-19.88
7 62 86 48 71
47.08
31 73 68 94 95
-11.19
100 87 44 75 43
108.04
72 25 62 39 57
54.74
...
```

Here is my training code. I used FANN_LINEAR because the other activation functions have outputs of 0, 1, or -1. I read that FANN_LINEAR is unbounded. So this should be applicable, right?

```
<?php
$num_input = 5;
$num_output = 1;
$num_layers = 6;
$num_neurons_hidden = 4;
$desired_error = 0.0001;
$max_epochs = 500000;
$epochs_between_reports = 1000;

$ann = fann_create_standard($num_layers, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1);

if ($ann) {
    fann_set_activation_function_hidden($ann, FANN_LINEAR);
    fann_set_activation_function_output($ann, FANN_LINEAR);

    $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . "/xor.data";
    if (fann_train_on_file($ann, $filename, $max_epochs, $epochs_between_reports, $desired_error))
        fann_save($ann, dirname(__FILE__) . "/xor_float.net");

    fann_destroy($ann);
}
```

Here is my testing code

```
<?php
$train_file = (dirname(__FILE__) . "/xor_float.net");
if (!is_file($train_file))
    die("The file xor_float.net has not been created! Please run simple_train.php to generate it");

$ann = fann_create_from_file($train_file);
if (!$ann)
    die("ANN could not be created");

$a = mt_rand(1, 100);
$b = mt_rand(1, 100);
$c = mt_rand(1, 100);
$d = mt_rand(1, 100);
$e = mt_rand(1, 100);

echo "Expecting $a $b $c $d $e => ".round($a + $b * $c / $d - $e, 2)."\n\n";

$input = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
$calc_out = fann_run($ann, $input);
echo "Result: ".print_r($calc_out, true);
fann_destroy($ann);
```

This is where it gets weird. I tried running this code multiple times, but the result is the same

```
fann$ php test2.php 
Expecting 94 67 95 40 85 => 168.13

Result: Array
(
    [0] => 89.329223632812
)
fann$ php test2.php 
Expecting 53 43 56 64 64 => 26.63

Result: Array
(
    [0] => 89.329223632812
)
fann$ php test2.php 
Expecting 18 85 57 94 30 => 39.54

Result: Array
(
    [0] => 89.329223632812
)
```

Can you give me some pointers to achieve my goal, that is, to approximate an arbitrary function using FANN. Do I have to increase my training data? Increase layers, or nodes per layer? Do I use another activation function.

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance, it seems like your network got stuck at certain weight configuration. That means that the weights, which are normally [initialized to small values around 0](https://secure.php.net/manual/kr/function.fann-randomize-weights.php), start changing their values to better fit the desired outputs. Since these changes are small, it is possible that, after a number of training epochs, they either don't «move enough» to find a nice combination of values, or they remain at a local minimum. There are a number of possible reasons (or just things to think about) for that:

- The input & output values that the network and the training algorithm have to process are relatively big (~range [-20,100]), compared with the initial values of the weights (~range [-1,1]). The easiest solution here is to [normalize](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#questions) the inputs & outputs to be A) small, B) centered around 0.
- The activation function`FANN_LINEAR` has no upper and lower limits. That may be good, but it can also lead to divergence. One option is to use `FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC`, which has limits, but also a transition zone where it is nearly linear. It works with normalized inputs and outputs.
- Sometimes the values of momentum and learning rate can lead to a bad learning. To make some diagnostics, you may want to plot a [learning error curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting#/media/File:Overfitting_svg.svg) of the error against the training epoch. Of course it is a bit more laborious, since you need to train each epoch separately (`fann_train_epoch` instead of `fann_train_on_file`).
- Lastly. I have no experience with big networks, but I could imagine that a single hidden layer could learn a problem like this. Why not giving it a try? It is already difficult enough to fix the number of 1 hidden layer, to just put more and more parameters in the equation ;)

Well, I hope that helps :)
Have fun with your nets!